# How do I select a package from apt list when the same package is available on two repos?

Tags: apt, plank

I want to install plank from the github repo,and added the repository but apt defaults to installing the package from the default Elementary OS ppa.(The first package)
[image]

How do I selectively install the second one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by specifying not only the name, but the full version:

```
apt install plank=0.11.89+git20211104…
```

You probably want to look into *apt pinning* to tell apt that it should prefer that specific PPA over your distro repos.

**BUT**: I don't know Elementary OS. I don't know whether you can just install Elementary OS packages on your Ubuntu Focal. If not, you might run into trouble.